# How to check whether the downloaded image is Portrait or Landscape in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I my project I have to populate the `UITableViewCell` with the image getting from the URL. That fine I converted the URL into Image, but problem arises how to check the image which is downloaded is Portrait or Landscape?

Comment: Simply check whether image.size.width > image.size.height then its landscape mode image. Have you tried this simple thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check this property of `UIImage`

```
    image.imageOrientation
```

More details,read this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImageOrientation)

Comment: imageOrientation property provide infos about its rotation state, not whether it's a landscape or portrait image.

Answer (score 3):

Follow below steps :

1. Download the complete image.
2. Get the Width & Height of that dynamically.
3. Now find ratio of it

> if(Width/Height>1)
>
> ```
>    // you can consider it as Landscape Image.
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>   // you can consider it as Portrait Image.
> ```

Please let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check its size:

```
UIImage* myImage = ...;
if (myImage.size.width > myImage.size.height)
{
    //landscape
}
else
{
    //portrait
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the width and height of the image by these condition..

```
UIImage* yourImg = @"imgName";

if (yourImg.size.width > yourImg.size.height)
{
  //yourImg is Landscape
}
else
{
  //yourImg is Portrait
}
```